# Replacing static code in a template file with a sidebar and widgets?

Tags: theme-development, widgets, sidebar

I am new to WordPress and need help. I am currently working on the site http://ecentriconline.com/surferbeachfront.

On this page, I want to display the left hand side as a widget. Right now, the left hand side is coded in the `index.php` page.

Please let me know the steps that I need to do to achive this.

Answer (score 3):

To speak generally, you need to define a sidebar for your theme (sidebars contain widgets) and display that sidebar in your template.

1. In your theme's functions.php file, register a dynamic sidebar using [`register_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)
2. Create a sidebar.php file in your theme directory that calls [`dynamic_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)
3. Make sure your other template files (or header.php/footer.php if that is more appropriate) calls [`get_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar)

If you need some more specifics, please feel free to update this question or ask a new question. (Seeing code is good, we can provide feedback on code.)